# Need Some help, Cann't Access NFC Card in SDK on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sdk, nfc

I have ACR122U reader and Mifare1k card, When I try sdk on windows 7 It's can't access the card, But XP It's can.(XP test in VMware)

result in Mifare Programming(SDK Project)

- I can Initialize and get Reader name but I can't Connect the card.(on Windows 7)

  > `Program ready`
  >   `?`
  >   `?`
- When I try on XP I can get Reader name, connect card, load authen key and authen key.

  > > `Program ready`
  > >     `Successful connection to ACR122 0`
  > >     `<FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF`
  > >     `>90 00`
  > >     `<FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 61 01`
  > >     `>90 00`
  > >     `Authentication success!`

*in ACR122UTool(application come with sdk),It's not sdk, but It's can send Direct command and got a result.(run on windows 7)

> > > `ACR122U PICC Interface`
> > >       `Connected to :  ACS ACR122 0`
> > >       `ACR122U APDU Command`
> > >       `< FF 82 00 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF`
> > >       `> 90 00`
> > >       `ACR122U APDU Command`
> > >       `< FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 00 61 01`
> > >       `> 90 00`

I don't understand, code from sdk can't access the card but application come with sdk can access the card and read write to card(run on windows 7)

PM. Sorry for my Eng (-_-")

Answer (score 0):

There are generic smart card drivers available in Windows but also specific drivers available from the ACS website.

I've had various issues with drivers in the past. My advice is to try the drivers from ACS.

Comment: i'm using driver from ACS website, release date 11-Nov-2013
 version 4.0.0.0 File size 3MB
from this (http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)

Comment: In a specific case like this you should probably contact ACS for support.

Comment: update my solution, I'm found error on vs2008 and when i move code to vs2010, it's not error

Comment: Just want to share. I had experienced this error too, In most cases, in visual studio, instead of downloading other version of VS you may also try changing the Target CPU to x86 on project properties.